# Constant variable already defined Xampp error

Tags: php, xampp

I am troubleshooting a site for someone and one of the error goes like this:

```
Constant serverusername already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\employee\inc\db.php on line 5
```

The contents of db.php is as follows:

```
<?php

//Database Connection Settings
define ('hostnameorservername','localhost'); //Your server name or hostname goes in here
define ('serverusername','root'); //Your database username goes in here
define ('serverpassword','');  //Your database password goes in here
define ('databasenamed','asset');  //Your database name goes in here

global $connection;
$connection = @mysql_connect(hostnameorservername,serverusername,serverpassword) or die('Connection could not be made to the SQL Server. Please report this system error at <font color="blue">info@servername.com</font>');
@mysql_select_db(databasenamed,$connection) or die('Connection could not be made to the database. Please report this system error at <font color="blue">info@servername.com</font>');   
?>
```

When I search the "serverusername" on the entire directory, I can't find it anywhere else other than on

```
:\xampp\htdocs\employee\inc\db.php on line 5
```

However the line:

```
include 'inc/db.php';
```

exists on numerous files.

What seems to be the problem? How can I resolve it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem  may be occurred due to include of db.php file many times on same page.

Try this :

```
    include_once 'inc/db.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
defined('hostnameorservername') or define('hostnameorservername', 'localhost');
defined('serverusername') or define('serverusername', 'root');
defined('serverpassword') or define('serverpassword', '');
defined('databasenamed') or define('databasenamed', 'asset');
```